# Pagination with angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJs. I am having a list of object which I am binding to the scope object and rendering in the view using the `ul and li` tags as shown below:

```
   <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
    <li data-ng-repeat="index in itemArray"><a href="#">{{$index+1}}</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
   </ul>
```

The `itemArray` is passed by the controller and binded using `$scope`. The `itemArray` is a  child array within a multi-dimension array which containing arrays having fixed number of items.

How can I fetch the child arrays on clicking of the `<a href=""` tag and fetch the corresponding sub array from the mainArray?

Comment: Check out bootstrap-ui it contains a pagination control you can hook into

Comment: Alternatively use ng click and pass in what you named index here.

Comment: Can you please let me know how since I assume that ng-click will again make a server call and then fetch the data? Or can we have a separate controller for the div section?

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to the question as you've presented it, where the arrays are fixed and already set. Other scenarios (e.g. where data needs to be retrieved from a server) will require a more complex solution.

Given an array that looks like

```
$scope.mainArray = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
$scope.itemArray = $scope.mainArray[0]; // init subarray with first set of values
```

setup a `$watch` to enable or disable the prev/next buttons based on whether the index of the subset array is found at the beginning or end of the main array

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
  return $scope.mainArray.indexOf($scope.itemArray);
}, function(idx){
  $scope.showPrev = (idx === 0) ? false : true;
  $scope.showNext = (idx === $scope.mainArray.length - 1) ? false : true;
});
```

where the buttons use ng-show with these corresponding values based on the index of the subset array in the main array:

```
<li ng-show="showPrev"><a>...</a></li>
<li ng-show="showNext"><a>...</a></li>
```

The previous and next buttons have their own scope functions which set the sub array based on an increment or decrement of the index

```
$scope.prev = function(arr){
  $scope.itemArray = $scope.mainArray[$scope.mainArray.indexOf(arr) - 1];
};

$scope.next = function(arr){
  $scope.itemArray = $scope.mainArray[$scope.mainArray.indexOf(arr) + 1];
};
```

The buttons pass the current sub array as an argument:

```
<a ng-click="prev(itemArray)">&laquo;</a>
<a ng-click="next(itemArray)">&raquo;</a>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LSMxL0NcRpT7T5SrezkQ?p=preview)